# When to double the consonant before the suffix "-able"

Tags: spelling, orthography

I'm not a native English speaker and I was wondering what is the rule that decides whether to write double letter before `-able`.

In programming, we have abused the (English) language in new ways, needing to name attributes of objects, which are derived from verbs, e.g.:

```
freezable
pushable
poppable
stoppable
interruptible
mappable
```

And so on. What is the rule? Does `p` always repeat while the other letters do not? :)

Comment: I'd answered if you didn't asked for the rules, because I think I have a solution for you. Most, if not all, of a noun-*able* are listed in dictionaries. For those verb-*able*, it's simple: double it in *-able* like when you double it in *-ing*, and a good dictionary would show how you would spell the *-ing* form explicitly. For example, ***[freeze](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/freeze)*** -> *freezing* (click on "Word Forms"), so *freezable*; *push* -> *pushing*, so *pushable*; *pop* -> *popping*, so *poppable*, and so on. This doesn't cover *interruptible*, though.

Comment: Also, when in doubt, you can always consult dictionaries or other online resources. Google is really useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there one P in "hoping" and two P's in "hopping"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/why-is-there-one-p-in-hoping-and-two-ps-in-hopping)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's a short vowel sound and a single consonant, then you double the consonant to signify that the vowel sound is supposed to stay short:

> map > mappable
>   hit > hittable
>   cancel > cancellable

Otherwise (if the vowel is already long, or if there is more than one consonant already) you don't need to double anything, because the vowel sound won't change anyway:

> junk > junkable
>   excite > excitable
>   quote > quotable

If you don't double the consonant when you're supposed to, it will look like the vowel is supposed to be long:

> mapable = "may-puh-bull", not "map-uh-bull"

Comment: That's harsh, as us non-natives also fight with the pronunciation :). Didn't know that junk was a verb.

Comment: Exception: when the verb ends in "c", it becomes "ck": mimic -> mimickable

Comment: I think ["cappable"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cappable) versus ["capable"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capable) might be a good example. Cappable isn't a very common word unless you are a brewer looking for cappable bottles, but I think it illustrates the difference in doubling the consonants because of vowel sounds.

Comment: hittable [buzzer]

Comment: This isn't true: "If it's a short vowel sound and a single consonant, then you double the consonant to signify that the vowel sound is supposed to stay short." For example: "cook" -> "cookable", "objection" -> "objectionable".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I do not consider either of your examples to be a short vowel sound for the given vowel(s); but, I could certainly clarify that the rule applies only to single vowels, not doubled or combined ones.

Comment: @Hellion There are other issues, too. For example, your guidance apparently requires "edittable", which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> - freezable
> - pushable
> - poppable
> - stoppable
> - interruptible
> - mappable

Quite simply,

1. If the base word is in CVC form, double the final consonant before -able.

Examples:

- Pop (CVC form) -> poppable
- Stop (CVC form) -> stoppable
- Map (CVC form) -> mappable

---

2. Do not double the final consonant before -able if:

   - the final consonant in base word is preceded by a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography))
   - the final consonant in base word is preceded by a [diphthong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong)
   - the final consonant in base word is followed by [magic/silent e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e)
   - the construction is CVCC or CVVC.

Examples:

- Freez**e** + able -> freezable (don't double the z because it's followed by magic e)
- Pu**sh** + able -> pushable (don't double sh because it's a digraph)
- Interru**pt** + ible -> interruptible (don't double the t because the construction is CVCC)

---

**Related answers:**

- Read [this answer (ELU)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/533789/365490) for when to remove final e.
- Read [this answer for when to double final consonant](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/248082/106592) (detailed explanation).